# How do I count the number of letters in a string?

Tags: ruby, string, count

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  How do I count the number of letters in a string?  This would include things like accented "a"s.  So for instance a string that looks like

```
"A."
```

has one "letter," and a string like

```
"123ABC"
```

has three.

Comment: regular expression?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" and “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". We'd like to see evidence of your effort. What did you try? Did you search and not find anything? Did you find stuff but it didn't help? Did you try writing code? If not, why? If so, what is the smallest code example that shows what you tried and why didn't it work? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write it for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To account for any Unicode character you could use the `\p{}` construct. Check the [Regexp docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) for more details.

Example:

```
'Aèméôfg1a'.scan(/[\p{L}]/).count 
=> 8
'A.èmôfg1a'.scan(/[\p{L}]/).count
=> 7
```

Comment: ...or use a POSIX bracket expression: `'Aèméôfg1a'.scan(/[[:alpha:]]/).count #=> 8`.